# How should I use WebApplication with multiple folders?

Tags: java, spring, wicket

Our wicket application extends WebApplication. We want to be able to trap access to secured pages when the session has expired, by time out or log out. It generally works, bringing up the SessionExpiredPage.

**WicketApplication.java:**

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication
{
    @Override
    public RuntimeConfigurationType getConfigurationType()
    {
        return RuntimeConfigurationType.DEPLOYMENT;
    }
    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage()
    {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Session newSession(Request request, Response response)
    {
        return new LMSSession(request);
    }
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(SessionExpiredPage.class);
        getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(SessionExpiredPage.class);
        getPageSettings().setRecreateBookmarkablePagesAfterExpiry(false);

        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
     }
}
```

We have several folders to contain pages for users with different roles. We have had to add a class in each folder to get the Spring injection to work. The WebApplication class and most of the same methods are overridden. This works but some pages do not get trapped when the session is expired. Is there a better way of connecting Spring in these folders?

**ClientApplication.java:**

```
public class ClientApplication extends WebApplication
{
    // Same methods
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();

        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I usually extend AuthenticatedWebApplication in typical wicket pattern (but security has nothing to spring). 2. could You set more precise question ;)

Comment: 1. Do I need to extend WebApplication for each folder? It is one application with multiple roles.

Comment: 2. Is there another way to get Spring connected to multiple folders?

Comment: re 1. Aplication is always one, multiple roles. https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_security_with_wicket We think in wicket in terms of "page" not "folder"

Comment: Our application does not look like section 22 at all. Are all page files supposed to be jammed into one folder?

Comment: You can put pages in sub-packages if you like. No need to put them all in the same folder. Typically you would add a `@AuthorizeInstantiation(roleXX)` annotation to them to prevent being opened by uses that don't have `roleXX`.